# Cannot read properties of undefined looping through XLSX file in Cypress test

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to convert values from an XLSX file into a JSON file in a Cypress test.

I have copied code form [this](https://blog.knoldus.com/reading-data-from-excel-file-cypress/) blog exactly, but when I hit the below line:

```
console.log(jsonData[index].data)
```

I get this error message:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')

Here is the code in my `spec.js` file:

```
describe('convert data to Json', () => {
    it('read data from xcel', () => {
        cy.parseXlsx('cypress/fixtures/excelData.xlsx').then((jsonData) => {
            const rowLength = Cypress.$(jsonData[0].data).length
            for (let index = 0; index < rowLength; index++) {
                var jsonData = jsonData[index].data
                console.log(jsonData[index].data)
                cy.writeFile("cypress/fixtures/xlsxData.json", { username: jsonData[0][0], password: jsonData[0][1] })
            }
        })
    })
})
```

And here is where my `parseXlsx` function is defined:

*Plguins/index.js*:

```
const xlsx = require('node-xlsx').default;
const fs = require('fs'); // for file
const path = require('path'); // for file path

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    parseXlsx({ filePath }) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const jsonData = xlsx.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
          resolve(jsonData);
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

My `cypress/fixtures/excelData.xlsx` file looks like this:

USERNAME    PASSWORD

Username1    Password1

Username2    Password2

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find a solution:

```
describe('convert data to Json', () => {
    it('read data from xcel', () => {
        cy.parseXlsx('cypress/fixtures/excelData.xlsx').then((jsonData) => {
            const rowLength = Cypress.$(jsonData[0].data).length

            for (let i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
                cy.log('Username: ' + jsonData[0].data[i][0]);
                cy.log('Password: ' + jsonData[0].data[i][1]);
                cy.writeFile("cypress/fixtures/xlsxData.json", { usernameValue: jsonData[0].data[i][0], passwordValue: jsonData[0].data[i][1] })
            }
        })
    })
})
```